# The product of two first-countable spaces is first-countable.

Tags: general-topology

Following a reference form "Elementos de Topología general" by Angel Tamariz and Fidel Casarrubias.

> **Theorem**
>
> Let be $X$ and $Y$ two first-countable topological spaces: then $X\times Y$ is first countable.
>
> *Proof*.  Let be $(x,y)\in X\times Y$. Since $X$ and $Y$ are first-countable there exist two open and numerable local bases $\mathcal{B}(x)$ and $\mathcal{B}(y)$ for $x$ and $y$. The collection
> $$
> \mathcal{A}=\{E\times F: E\in\mathcal{B}(x)\wedge F\in\mathcal{B}(y)\}
> $$
> is numerable and so we will have proved the assertion if we show  that $\mathcal{A}$ is a local basis for $(x,y)$ in $X\times Y$. Well let be $V$ a neighborhood of $(x,y)$. Since the projections $\pi_X$ and $\pi_Y$ are open functions it result that $\pi_X(V)$ and $\pi_Y(V)$ are neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$: so there exist   $E\in\mathcal{B}(x)$ and $F\in\mathcal{B}(y)$ such that $x\in E\subseteq\pi_X(V)$ and $y\in F\subseteq\pi_Y(V)$, from which we aruge that
> $$
> (x,y)\in E\times F\subseteq V 
> $$
> and so, since $E\times F\in\mathcal{A}$, we conclude that $X\times Y$ is first-countable.

Well in the previous proof I didn't understeand the implication
$$
\{x\in E\subseteq\pi_X(V)\wedge y\in F\subseteq\pi_Y(V)\}\Rightarrow(x,y)\in E\times F\subseteq V
$$
since indeed it result that
$$
\{x\in E\subseteq\pi_X(V)\wedge y\in F\subseteq\pi_Y(V)\}\Rightarrow(x,y)\in E\times F\subseteq \pi_X(V)\times\pi_Y(V)
$$
but generally $\pi_X(V)\times\pi_Y(V)\neq V$! So could someone explain to me this point?

Anyway I think I found an another way to prove the statment. Here my alternative proof.

Well first of all we consider that for any point $x$ of some topological space $X$ it result that for each neighborhood $V_x$ of $x$ there exist a open set $U$ such that $x\in U\subseteq V_x$ so, since any open set is a neighborhood of its points, we can prove the statment using local and open basis: indeed for what we observe it result that any (numerable) local basis contains a open (numerable) local basis.

Well let be $(X,\mathcal{T})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{S})$ two first-countable topological spaces: so we consider the collection
$$
\mathcal{B}=\{\pi^{-1}_X(E)\cap\pi^{-1}_Y(F):E\in\mathcal{T}\wedge F\in\mathcal{S}\}\equiv\{E\times F:E\in\mathcal{T}\wedge F\in\mathcal{S}\}
$$
that is a basis for the product space $X\times Y$. Then let be $(x,y)\in X\times Y$: so form the previous observation we consider the open and numerable local bases $\mathcal{B}(x)$ and $\mathcal{B}(y)$ for $x=\pi_X(x,y)\in X$ and $y=\pi_Y(x,y)\in Y$. Well now we consider the collection
$$
\mathcal{A}=\{E\times F: E\in\mathcal{B}(x)\wedge F\in\mathcal{B}(y)\}
$$
so observing that $|\mathcal{A}|\equiv|\mathcal{B}(x)\times\mathcal{B}(y)|=|\mathcal{B}(x)||\mathcal{B}(y)|\le\aleph_0$ and that the elements of $\mathcal{A}$ are open neighborhood of $(x,y)$ it's clear that if we will prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is a local basis for $(x,y)$ we will have proved the $X\times Y$ is first-conuntable. Well let be $V_{(x,y)}$ and open neighborhood of $(x,y)$: in particular since for each point $z\in X\times Y$  of some open set $U$ there exist $B\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $z\in B\subseteq U$, we suppose that $V_{(x,y)}\in\mathcal{B}$, that is $V_{(x,y)}=E\times F$ for some $E\in\mathcal{T}$ and $F\in\mathcal{S}$. Well if $(x,y)\in V_{(x,y)}=E\times F\equiv\pi^{-1}_X(E)\cap\pi^{-1}_Y(F)$ we have that
$$
x=\pi_X((x,y)\in\pi_X(V_{(x,y)})=E\in\mathcal{T}\wedge y=\pi_Y((x,y))\in\pi_Y(V_{(x,y)})=F\in\mathcal{S}
$$
and so, since $E$ and $F$ are open sets and since each open set is a neighborhood of its points, there exist $E'\in\mathcal{B}(x)$ and $F'\in\mathcal{B}(y)$ such that $x\in E'\subseteq E$ and $y\in F'\subseteq F$, from which it result that
$$
(x,y)\in E'\times F'\subseteq E\times F=V_{(x,y)}
$$
and so, since $E'\times F'\in\mathcal{A}$, we conclude that $X\times Y$ is first-countable.

Well is my proof correct? Could some help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quite right in your criticism at the beginning: from having local base elements inside $\pi_X[E]$ and $\pi_Y[E]$ we do not necessarily get a product set inside $E$ itself.

The correction is even simpler: if $E$ is open and contains $(x,y)$, first use (as you seem to do) that there is a standard product basic open set $U \times V$ such that $U$ is open in $X$, $V$ is open in $Y$ and $(x,y) \in U \times V \subseteq E$.

Then directly appeal to the fact that we have a $B_1 \in \mathcal{B}(x)$ such that $x \in B_1 \subseteq U$ (as we have a local base in $X$) and similarly in $Y$ we have $B_2 \in \mathcal{B}(y)$ such that $y \in B_2 \subseteq V$ and then by construction $B_1 \times B_2 \in \mathcal{A}$ and $$(x,y) \in B_1 \times B_2 \subseteq U \times V \subseteq E$$
as required.

Some of what you wrote is redundant I think, but the idea is the same: just use what the basic open sets of $X \times Y$ look like directly and only appealing to openness of projections will not be enough.